# Error installing VirtualBox on Kali Linux following the Kali doc

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, virtualbox, documentation

https://stackexchange.com/users/9328287/telcom I found a very useful and meaningful answer of yours about this error:

```
E: The repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian n/a         Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is       therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

For my own understanding Oracle VirtualBox was not intentionally designed for Kali OS.

Almost two years after I have followed the official Kali doc for installing Virtual Box on Kali Linux system and still have the same error at this step:

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- \
  | sudo apt-key add -
```

Is there any possible way to install VirtualBox on Kali Linux?

I am a newbie

Comment: The downvotes are presumably because Kali is a *really bad idea* for a desktop distro, especially for someone unfamiliar enough with linux that the above is an actual question they need help with.

Comment: @Shadur A typo in kali docs has been fixed now.

Comment: @GAD3R Which does not change the fact that *Kali should not be used as a desktop OS, especially by people who are unfamiliar with linux in general*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To answer the question:**

From kali documentation: [Installing VirtualBox on Kali (Host)](https://www.kali.org/docs/virtualization/install-virtualbox-host/)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade -y
[ -f /var/run/reboot-required ] && sudo reboot -f
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- \
| sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian buster contrib" \
| sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
```

`lsb_release -cs` print `kali-rolling` you need to change it to `buster` (typo in the above command line in the officiel docs. I have submitted an edit [b949ad5b](https://gitlab.com/gad3r/kali-docs/-/commit/b949ad5b5eac47041c3e249479d18105a90cd536))

```
sudo apt update
udo apt install -y dkms
```

> Now its time to install VirtualBox itself (along with its Extension Pack to expand VirtualBox's advanced features).

```
sudo apt install -y virtualbox virtualbox-ext-pack
```

Generally you don't need to install it from oracle repository because `virtualbox` is available in kali repositories.

**Edit**

[Merge Request has been merged 61!](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/documentation/kali-docs/-/merge_requests/61), the typo is fixed now in [the kali docs](https://www.kali.org/docs/virtualization/install-virtualbox-host/).

```
kali@kali:~$ echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian buster contrib" \
  | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
kali@kali:~$
```

[Merge branch 'gad3r-master-patch-41840' into 'master'](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/documentation/kali-docs/-/commit/1f4593878b045179ecb05472c3c5a0184fa13f8a)

Comment: thanks ! definitely it works